# Black screen when booting Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: 16.04, raspberrypi

I first used Snappy Ubuntu Core, worked with no problem. But it was a little bit minimal for my taste.

Now I try to install: `ubuntu-16.04.3-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz`

I'm using Etcher to create a bootable USB (no errors or something like that when  I create it). When I later put my SD-Card in the rasp the screen is just black, nothing happens.

Any clue why? Is there a log or something that could give me more information?

(I'm using this guide: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi)

Comment: It may not work with Etcher. The guide says `dd`...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with this image on a Raspberry Pi 2, there's no output on the display when the kernel is booting.

I have to wait a few moments until text is visible on the console.